# Error on getting DirectoryInfo with GetFileSystemInfos()

Tags: c#, directory, directoryinfo

I get an error when I'm trying to get a `DirectoryInfo` because there is some read only file and folder.

How can I skip them?

```
var dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(Path_Tb_Path.Text);
var entries = dirinfo.GetFileSystemInfos("**", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: "I get an error" isn't enough information - what *exactly* was the error?

Comment: Based on the code you have provided, a file/folder being readonly should not throw an error for just getting `FileSystemInfo`s. It's possible that you are running into some permission error. But as Jon noted, without the error details, it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 4.0 you could use the [`EnumerateFileSystemInfos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383689.aspx) method. For example you could write the following recursive method which will swallow the `UnauthorizedAccessException` for some files and only include those files in the result for which you have permission to access:

```
public static IEnumerable<FileSystemInfo> SafeGetFileSystemInfosRecursive(DirectoryInfo directory, string searchPattern)
{
    try
    {
        return directory
            .EnumerateFileSystemInfos(searchPattern)
            .Concat(
                directory
                    .EnumerateDirectories()
                    .SelectMany(x => SafeGetFileSystemInfosRecursive(x, searchPattern))
            );
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<FileSystemInfo>();
    }
}
```

and then call the method like that:

```
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Path_Tb_Path.Text);
FileSystemInfo[] entries = SafeGetFileSystemInfosRecursive(dirInfo, "**").ToArray();
```